# How can I get the class name with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a Javascript function where it reads the class of the selected element and adds the class `active`. How can I get the class of the HTML element where my function is?

I tried to make an Javascript function with `document.getElementsByClassName(class)`, but that doesn't work.

```js
function menuicon(){
  var className = $('div').attr('class');
  className.$(className).addClass("active");
}
```

```html
<section class="menubar">
  <div class="menuicon" onclick="classAdd()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="home">
  <button class="hbutton" onclick="classAdd()"></button>
</section>
```

I want that the Javascript function reads out the class of the HTML element where the function is placed in.

Comment: Either [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return) or [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the element to the function:

```
onclick="classAdd(this)"
```

Then in the function, you just use `.addClass`, you don't need to use `className`.

```
function classAdd(element) {
    $(element).addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: or he could just use `onclick="classAdd()"` and reference `this` in the function, or would this be wrong due to some reason?

Comment: That won't work, `this` isn't passed when you call a function like that.

Comment: Alternative is to embrace jquery and set the event in the javascript instead of using `onclick=` - then you get `this`.

Comment: can set the event even without jQuery sicne it is embracing good coding practices, I am baffeled that after three years of `.js` I never figgured out that `.onclick` is not equal to writting onclick inside HTML in this way...

Comment: @despamigros Use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet only include 'active' in the classList of the div

```
var classAdd = function() {
                  var menuIcon = document.querySelector('div.menuicon');
                      menuIcon.addEventListener('click',() => {
                                                    menuIcon.classList.add('active');
                                                 });
                          }
```

Comment: This will require two clicks. The first click adds the event listener, the second click adds the class.

Answer (score 0):

If encase you want to stick with the `div` and the `menuicon` class.
Below code will work fine for you.

```
function classAdd() {
    $("div.menuicon").attr("class", "menuicon active");
}
```